# RandomAccessFile readFully EOF exception

Tags: java

I get EOF exception using RandomAccessFile class and read or readFully methods.
The length of the data I am trying to read is 1 and offset is 0 so I wouldn't expect receiving EOF exception. I see the file is created and written into it successfully.

This is my code:

```
private static void createFile() {

    if(pub_f != null)
    {
        System.out.println("file already exists");
    }   
    try 
    {
        pub_f = new RandomAccessFile("file.bin", "rw");
        pub_f.setLength(10*1024);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("fail to open file. Exception message: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(f == null)
    {
        System.out.println("fail to open file");
    }   
    else
    {
        System.out.println("file created");
    }

    //initialize file content
    for(int i = 0; i<10240; i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            pub_f.write(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("fail to initialize file content. Exception message: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public int ReadFile(int offset, int length, byte[] data) 
{
    if (pub_f == null)
    {
        System.out.println("fail to open file for reading");
        return -1;
    }

    try 
    {
        pub_f.readFully(data, offset, length);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("fail to read from file. Exception message: "+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In my main:

```
int len = 1;
int offset = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[512];
createFile();
readFile(offset, len, data);
```

Please can someone help to find what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to [`seek` (set the file pointer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)) back to the start of the file after writing to it, so it will try to read from the end of the file. Which will give you the aptly named `EOFException`.

Add a call to `seek(0L)` before reading, to start reading from the beginning of the file.

```
int len = 1;
int offset = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[512];
createFile();
pub_f.seek(0L); // <---- set the file pointer back to the start of the file.
readFile(offset, len, data);
```

Comment: I thought the offset serves as the seek... Does it mean that offset indicates offset from where the file is pointing to?

Comment: The offset that you were providing is the offset in the array where it starts writing data - if you pass offset 1 in the read call, the data that was read will be written in the array from offset 1 instead of the usual zero